# Alternative to ClickOnce for auto-update?

Tags: wpf, windows-10, clickonce, system-tray

I'm using ClickOnce setup to deploy a WPF app internally in our organization. A new version is build on a build server and copied to a location in the network, where the ClickOnce-Setup can find it - and install the update the next time the user starts the applications. This is pretty much what I need.

But ... the WPF application is a tray-app (running with an icon in the system tray of windows). Since every new version of the app is handled as a new app, the icon is always hidden after an update and all users have to manually bring it to visibility in their taskbar settings - what's annoying and not acceptable.

Thus, I looking for an alternative to ClickOnce-Seupt to auto-update an once installed application (replacing the exe and some dlls) at startup. Is there any?

Comment: WIX toolset: http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows). It's an open-source installation and update framework for Windows desktop apps.

If you are on Windows 10 version 1803 or later, you may also want to take a look at `.appinstaller`. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this.

**Handling auto updates for sideloaded UWP and Desktop Bridge apps:** https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/

There are also commercial options such as for example [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) available to handle this.

Comment: Squirrel is deprecated. Would there be any other open source solution?

Comment: @Luishg: [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be found here, even though it's not open source:

[simpldeploy.com](https://simpldeploy.com)